# simple computation of mysql sums & php. How to do?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables, computation

I need to do a computation within my website. I have all parameters but couldn't figure out how to combine them to one result.

**Please help me to solute this!**

I get the data from mysql database: (shorted)

```
   <?php
     $res = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(status) FROM ' . 'success_rate', $con);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM))
        {
           $rate = trim($row[0]);    ?>

<?php
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM ' . 'user_registration', $con);
        ?>
```

So i get 2 classic params

**What I need is to have just one Number in the end.** This is how the computation shall work:

```
((<?= $status ?> / <?= $2nd ?>)*100)-200   =  result
```

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using PDO or Mysqli. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: `$2nd` is an outright syntax error. why such a convoluted structure? Why could you not try `$answer = (($status / $second) * 100) - 200;`?

Comment: also the `{` never closes ...

Comment: it's just a snipped - i will try answer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems. First, the `mysql` extension is depreciated. Use `mysqli` instead. When you do that you change `mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)` to `mysqli_fetch_array($res)`.

Next, you need to close the `if` statement brackets. You only have an opening bracket.

That second code snippet is a syntax errpr. Do this: `$result = (($status / $second)*100)-200`

Beyond that, I don't know what else you want because you haven't given enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the second query also:

```
$rate = 0;
$count = 0;

$res = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(status) FROM success_rate', $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$rate = $row[0];

$res = mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM user_registration', $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$count = $row[0];

if ($count != 0) {
    echo (($status / $count) * 100) - 200;
} else {
    echo 'Count was 0';
}
```

- Do not use mysql functions because the are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
- Use an IDE to inspect your syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shorten the code by returning the result with one query, you could do it this way:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT (((SUM(status) / (SELECT Count(*) FROM user_registration)) * 100) - 200) as result FROM success_rate") or die (mysql_error());
```

Note however:
if the second parameter is smaller than the first, you will get a negative number in the end, because you're subtracting 200 in the end.

For example: IF SUM(status) = 10 AND Count(*) = 100, THEN your result is -190

```
((10/100)*100)-200 = -190
```